# Function passed to element ref in React never runs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an array of React symbols, and passing a function to `ref` which never runs, for some reason. I believe I'm following the documentation on how to do this. By the time this is done rendering `this.divElement` should be set to the native DOM node of the last element, but since the function never runs, it remains `null`.

```
divElement = null;

render() {

    const activeKeys = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

    const infoDivs = activeKeys.map((key, i) => {
      console.log(key, i);
      return (
        <div 
          className="test"
          ref={ (divElement) => { alert('This never runs?'); this.divElement = divElement } }
        >
          Some div text.
        </divs>
      )
    });

    return (
        <span className="info-container container">
            { this.infoDivs }
        </span>
    )
}
```

I know the loop is running, as it logs three times as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you meant to use `{infoDivs}`, not `{ this.infoDivs }`. Your `infoDivs` variable that returns your elements, is just a variable inside `render`, not a class field.

Elements from `infoDivs` are never rendered, so the `divElement` remains `undefined`.

```
return (
    <span className="info-container container">
        {infoDivs}
    </span>
)
```